# Apply confusion in Do loop

Tags: printing, permutation

I am trying to apply `InversePermutation` on a list of sublists of selected permutation elements. First I am trying to see if I am able to reach every element,

```
temp = {{Cycles[{}]}, {Cycles[{}], Cycles[(12)]}, {Cycles[{}], 
   Cycles[(13)]}}
```

So the code I have tried to print all is

```
k = 1; i = 1; Do[Do[Apply[Print, i], {i, k}], {k, temp}]
```

which gives 
$\{\}\{\}\{1 2\}\{\}\{1 3\}....$ it pics only content of `Cycle`. So, I changed it a bit as,

```
k = 1; i = 1; Do[Do[Apply[Print, {i}], {i, k}], {k, temp}]
```

Surprisingly it started to take all the contents with `Cycle` prefix along, giving

$\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}]\}\\ \left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\}....$

What I could not understand is that putting `{i}` instead of `i` changed what ?
**Edit:** I am not able to replace this `Print` with `InversePermutation`.It doesn't respond if I replace Print with it. Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your definitions `k=1` and `i=1` make little difference, as `i` and `k` are local in the do loops. To see how the code behaves we actually have to look at the range specifications for `k` first.

`temp` is a list, so values for `k` be taken from this list. But the values for `k` are then always lists as well, as `temp` is a list of lists. So also in the inner loop we have for every value of `k` a `Do` loop of the form `Do[expr, {i, list}]`. So `i` takes every element of this list as a value.

I am unsure if you meant this to happen. At least you are finding all the `Cycles` :). But it confuses me that you would set `i` and `k` to 1 then..

**Suggestion**

Evaluate

```
Clear[i, k]
Do[Print[i], {k, temp}, {i, k}]
```

> Cycles[{}], Cycles[{}], Cycles[12]...

You see that you need no definitions for `i` and `k`? And that you can do with only one `Do` loop? And that you don't need `Apply`?

Also evaluate

```
Map[Print, Flatten[temp]];
```

> Cycles[{}], Cycles[{}], Cycles[12]...

**Further note**

`Apply` is a function that changes the head of an expression. `Apply[Print, i]` is generally not good code in a `Do` loop where `i` is a variable, as in case `i=1` for example, `i` has no proper head, as the integer 1 is a so called atom of *Mathematica*.

`Apply[Print, {1}]` is "good code", as the head of {1} is `List` and {1}.

Anyway, as it turns out, `i` is never 1 inside the Do loops so I guess this doesn't matter.

In your example, if you use `Apply[Print, Cycles[{}]]`, that becomes `Print[{}]`. If you do `Apply[Print, {Cycles[{}]}]`, that becomes `Print[Cycles[{}]]`.

Comment: your explanation is very informative, thanks a lot.

Comment: @rafiki Okido, no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your `Do` loops, you can combine them into a single `Do` expression; I will replace `Do` with `Table` to return all evaluations in nested lists, and I will use an arbitrary head `label` to show which parts are assigned to `i` in each loop:

```
Table[label[i], {k, temp}, {i, k}]
```

> ```
> {{label[Cycles[{}]]}, {label[Cycles[{}]], label[Cycles[12]]},
>  {label[Cycles[{}]], label[Cycles[13]]}}
> ```

Note that the same expression can be produced with:

```
Map[label, temp, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{label[Cycles[{}]]}, {label[Cycles[{}]], label[Cycles[12]]},
>  {label[Cycles[{}]], label[Cycles[13]]}}
> ```

Now we can address this part of your question:

> What I could not understand is that putting {i} instead of i changed what?

The operation `Apply[ff, expr]` replaces the head of `expr` with `ff`.  In the case of `{stuff}` the head is `List`, so you simply get `ff[stuff]`.  Combined with the above, and using `Scan` in place of `Map` (which has similar syntax), with `{i}` you are therefore just doing the equivalent of:

```
Scan[Print, temp, {2}]
```

Depending on what you want to do you may find value in `Level`:

```
Level[temp, {2}]
```

> ```
> {Cycles[{}], Cycles[{}], Cycles[12], Cycles[{}], Cycles[13]}
> ```

Comment: ya yesterday night after reading your other post on loops, I tried the same and could do it. Thanks for posting here in more refined way.